# PHP Soap call xml isnt formated correctly

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to talk to a SOAP api a partner provided us with.
I create the client using a WSDL:

$client = new SoapClient('Path/to/WSDL',array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => 1));

and then call a function like this:

```
var_dump($client->__call('gsLogin',[new SoapParam("0", '0'), 
                                                new SoapParam("User", 'sUser'), 
                                                new SoapParam("Password", 'sPassword'), 
                                                new SoapParam("Database", 'sDatabase'), 
                                                new SoapParam(1, 'lDivision'), 
                                                new SoapParam("", 'sError')]));
```

out comes this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.namespace.de/">
        <env:Body>
            <ns1:gsLogin/>
                <sUser>User</sUser>
                <sPassword>Password</sPassword>
                <sDatabase>Database</sDatabase>
                <lDivision>1</lDivision>
                <sError></sError>
        </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

As you can see gsLogin is closed immediately with the /.
The parameters go nowhere and I get back the error that no user was given.

Any idea what causes this problem or how to fix it?

Comment: What is the intended effect of `new SoapParam("0", '0')`? I can't see it in the output, so wonder if it's messing up the serialization somehow, since `<0>` wouldn't be a valid XML element name.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't need to call `__call` explicitly, the intention is that you use the remote verb as the actual method name, and the request parameters as individual PHP parameters: `$client->gsLogin(new SoapParam(...), new SoapParam, ...)`

Comment: The first SoapParam seems to be getting ignored or atleast didnt show up in $client->__getLastRequest(). I added the "empty" Param so "sUser" shows up in the xml file

Comment: nice to know, but the first variable is still getting swallowed and gsLogin is still broken

Comment: Well, that sounds like a problem in itself - *why* is a parameter being ignored? Is there something that is expected there? Have you tried using an associative array with the parameter names as keys, as suggested on https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php ?